# Tweepy Encoding Error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 14-14: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, tweepy, python-unicode

I have read some other answers on StackOverflow, and I'm aware (roughly) of what the issue is: Tweepy and Python have some difficulty converting certain characters (most probably bitcoins), and I see some of the resolutions, but I'm too programmatically challenged to apply them (as you can guess from my username).

Would appreciate any help in fixing this. Using latest Python 3.x.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json


#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret="" #Removed for privacy
atoken="" #Removed for privacy
asecret="" #Removed for privacy


class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)

        tweet = all_data["text"]

        print((tweet))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer online.

You add an ascii wrapper:

tweet = ascii(all_data["text"])